# How to lock a file in onedrive using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I am making a vba Programm that access a file in OneDrive and edits it. However, I don't want two users to be able to edit the file at the same time. I can't completly lock the file, because while one user is editing, the others might still read it.
I used to lock the file with something like this:

```
If varForReadOnly = False Then
   wbExample.LockServerFile
End If
```

This never worked on my version of the programm, but always worked on my client for months. Now, after changing the OneDrive file's name, this has stopped working all of a sudden, with the same error it had in my computer.

Does anyone knows what I did wrong, or what I can do to lock the file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching, I found out how to do this. I am going to leave the answer here, because I still didn't find any answer to this question.

You must use the CheckIn() and CheckOut methods. Something like this:

```
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(varForFilePath) = True Then
   Workbooks.CheckOut(varForFilePath)
   Set wbVarForWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(varForFilePath)
   'works with workbook and in the end check it back     
   wbVarForWorkbook.CheckIn SaveChanges:=True
Else
   'message about busy workbook
End If
```

This methods are complex and there are other things you should be careful about when working with them, but this is the basic answer for what methods to use to replace LockServerFile and lock a file in OneDrive so that only one user at a time can edit it.